# Partitioning correctly for GPT in BIOS system

Tags: partition, gpt

I am in doubt whether I have partitioned my hdd correctly as GPT on a BIOS motherboard. I used *gparted* to partition and I don't know if I aligned the beginning/end of the disk correctly, used correct flags etc. The disk in question is `sdc`:

```
    $ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL           MOUNTPOINT
sda                           
├─sda1 ntfs   System Reserved 
├─sda2 ntfs   win7            
└─sda3 ntfs   WINYANCI        
sdb                           
├─sdb1                        
└─sdb5 ext4   YAHSI           
sdc                           
├─sdc1                        
├─sdc2 swap                   [SWAP]
├─sdc3 ext4                   /
├─sdc4 ext4                   /home
├─sdc5 ext4   store1          
└─sdc6 ntfs   store2          
sdd                           
├─sdd1                        
├─sdd2 ntfs   DEPO            
└─sdd5 ntfs   HUSUSI          
sr0
```

here is what `gdisk` shows:

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2758BB06-C7E7-451B-9C92-F1B278721BB6
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3437 sectors (1.7 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048            6143   2.0 MiB     EF02  
   2            6144         8394751   4.0 GiB     8200  
   3         8394752        76754943   32.6 GiB    EF00  
   4        76754944       174409727   46.6 GiB    0700  
   5       174409728      1346283519   558.8 GiB   0700  
   6      1346283520      1953523711   289.6 GiB   0700
```

and `parted` shows [this](http://paste.debian.net/83003/).

Are there any mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if all partitions are properly aligned to 1MiB you should divide the start sector by 8. Let's see:

```
1346283520/8=168285440
174409728/8=21801216
76754944/8=9594368
8394752/8=1049344
6144/8=768
2048/8=256
```

It looks good. The next thing is to check if the size of the partitions can also be divided by 8:

```
(1953523711−1346283520+1)/8=75905024
(1346283519−174409728+1)/8=146484224
(174409727−76754944+1)/8=12206848
(76754943−8394752+1)/8=8545024
(8394751−6144+1)/8=1048576
(6143−2048+1)/8=512
```

It also looks good. You divide by 8 because of the technology called "advanced format". Just look at the following images:

[image]

[image]

But this concerns only disks that have this feature. If you don't have a disk with the "advanced format" technology, it doesn't matter what alignment you use. Most of modern disks use this thing, and most of partition tools align partitions to 1MiB by default.

Comment: What about the `EF00` flag of sdc3 (my / partition). I have no EFI but it's marked as an *EFI System*? PS: I do have "advanced format" on sdc, that's why I bothered with GPT :)

Comment: If you have a disk which size is <2GiB, you don't have to use GPT. "Advanced format" just means that system uses 8 sectors instead of one, and that's it. As for the `EF00` flag, I think you should ask another question.

Comment: I probably should have asked another question about the flags (or *types* as gdisk calls them) but I have figured what was wrong with them: apparently `gparted` doesn't correctly use them. I fixed them using `cgdisk`. I changed `EF00` to `8300` as it is an Linux partition not an EFI.